# Python Access odbc and should skip the row

Tags: python

I am using MS Access to import the table information. Table is below:

```
Field1   Field2
U1a14    High Speed Link
U0001    Medium speed data
U0022    Low Speed Link
```

My code value is like: `code = U1a14
code = U0001
code = B11DB (This code is not present in table)`

I am connecting to odbc and searching for code in table.

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;SafeTransactions=0;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:\PYTHON27;DBQ=C:\PYTHON27\iso14229dtcs.mdb;')
cursor1 = connection.cursor()
cursor1.execute("SELECT Field2 FROM Table Where Field1 = '{}'".format(code))

for row in cursor1.fetchone():
  print row
```

I am getting error:

```
error:
for row in cursor1.fetchone():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How Can I fix it, If the code is not present in my Table, it should skip and print only existing row

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to the following, check `cursor1.fetchone()` is not NULL.

```
    connection = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;SafeTransactions=0;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:\PYTHON27;DBQ=C:\PYTHON27\iso14229dtcs.mdb;')
    cursor1 = connection.cursor()
    cursor1.execute("SELECT Field2 FROM Table Where Field1 = '{}'".format(code))
    row = cursor1.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
        print row[0], row[1]
        row = cursor1.fetchone()
    cursor1.close()
    connection.close()
```

Comment: I am getting error: File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pypyodbc.py", line 1061, in __getitem__
    return tuple.__getitem__(self,field)
IndexError: tuple index out of range